# Unable to perform any PHP operations in an Ajax application

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get

My Ajax application was working fine, until I implemented an if statement in the PHP script... then like a contagious disease it seems that if I do anything to the data in PHP it returns nothing back to the Javascript layer.

All I can do is echo the data back...

For instance the query string I'm sending to the PHP reads...

```
index.back3.php?form=login&json={"email":"mo@maurice-campobasso.com","password":"asdasdfas"}
```

and I know its getting there because in the simplest debugging PHP file (index.back3.php) that I created all I have is a simple echo statement... and it never fails to send back the data to the Javascript file.

when index.back3.php reads

```
<?php echo $_GET[json]; ?>
```

the alert that I have triggering off in the javascript reliably spits out the json string.

also when it reads

```
<?php echo $_GET[form]; ?>
```

when I get any more complicated than that nothing comes back to the javascript.  Even a simple concatenation...

```
<?php echo ($_GET[form] . $_GET[json]); ?>
```

...returns nothing!

A simple if...else statement also returns nothing.

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_GET[form]) { 
     echo "no!";
    } else {
     echo "yes!";
    }

?>
```

And this important operation also...

```
<?php

 $array = json_decode($GET[json], true);

 var_dump($array);
?>
```

returns nothing.

OK... so just to make sure everything is above board here is my Ajax output function in the Javascript layer.

```
function responseAjax() {

 if (myRequest.readyState == 4)  {

  if(myRequest.status == 200) {  

   var foo = myRequest.responseText;

   alert(foo);

  } else {

   alert("An error has occured:  " + myRequest.statusText);
  }
 }
}
```

Can someone please explain what's going on?  I'm truly stumped.

Comment: Please please don't put a password into a GET query!

Comment: Quote your strings! `$_GET['something']` not `$_GET[something]`

Comment: Was the JSON in the query string urlencoded? Fire up Firebug, look at the real network data.

Comment: Haha... don't worry Billy I won't be when I roll it out.  Its just for ease as I set up everything else.

Comment: http://local.produkshunator.com/Produkshunator/index.back3.php?form=login&json={%22email%22:%22mo@maurice-campobasso.com%22,%22password%22:%22GOD%22}&rand=99496806

Comment: thank's Mario as you can see from above the the JSON is url encoded.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['form'] is the right way.

and using form as variable name is not at all good.

use anyother variable and pass $_GET['formname'].

Try to access the php page directly through url and  pass the parameters , check first the php

return error or its working propelry.

You can use PHP , jquery and ajax in simple ways.

try to find .post or .get methods in jquery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});

Comment: Thanks zod, I did what you said and the php file on its own does execute the if statement!  The problem must be in the javascript.

Comment: did yu change variable name form. dont confuse javascript with form

Comment: jQuery is high on my priorities to learn.  I think I may read up on it after a nights sleep...

Comment: leave jquery..yu ddnt answer about variable name :(

Comment: I changed the variable name,but the application still didn't work... I even used quotes $_GET['formname']... The PHP file on its own however did work.

Comment: it says "missing ) in parenthetical - alert(foo);"  I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(!isset($_GET[form]) { 
>  echo "no!";
> } else {
>  echo "yes!";
> }
> ```
>
> ?>

you are missing a closing parenthesis in the if statement. And as said a few times before, put quotes around your array keys.

While in development, you should also maybe turn on error_reporting to E_ALL. it helps find out what a small error might be.

Comment: Oh and I do have error_reporting set to E_ALL... but as I have learned in the answer above the problem appears to be with the Javascript, not the PHP so I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out, it had to do with a line of code which I omitted from this post, because I thought it was reduntant.  The full version of the function went like this.

```
function responseAjax() {

    if (myRequest.readyState == 4)  {       

        if(myRequest.status == 200) {       

            var foo         =   myRequest.responseText;     

            var cookieData      =   eval("(" + foo + ")");  //this was the problem!!

            alert(foo);             

            document.cookie = 'email ='     + cookieData.email      + '; path=/';
            document.cookie = 'firstname =' + cookieData.FirstName  + '; path=/';

        } else {

            alert("An error has occured:  " + myRequest.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

It was the 'var cookieData' line... though I'm not sure why.